# Pull form-related data from column A in Google sheets and populate columns b,C,D and E with specific data

Tags: google-sheets, automation, zapier

I want to able to specify data from Column A to be populated to columns B, C, D and E.

The data in column A looks like this:
Name: John LastName: Doe Mejladress: john.doe@madpeople.com Company: Mad People

How do I do this? Thanks!

I tried this to extract the mail address:
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"Mejladress: (.+)")

And got an error even on that. So not thinking my chances of populating the others are high either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(ifna(trim(regexextract(A2,"Name:(.*)LastName:(.*)Mejladress:(.*)Company:(.*)"))))
```

[image]

if you wish to try each part individually, go with:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"Mejladress: (.*?) ")
```

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response and correct answer. I got all of the data out the way I wanted it to record. Thanks!

Comment: I did notice now though that it does not pull all of the data for some cells. So I have copied the code all down column B so that it refers to A3, A4, A5 etc for the source data. But it does not copy data from there in all cases. My A column is full of like 2590 entries, and about 180 have populated the B,C,D,E cells. Any idea why this is so?

Comment: the formula is designed keeping in context the single example you shared. its bound to fail when the pattern does not match with any variations that may exist within

Comment: yes thanks. I see in the source data that in some cases "mejladress" is actually written as "Mejl". Those are the ones not populating.